# Django 1.6 - could not locate custom cache backend

Tags: python, django, django-1.6

In django 1.3 we had cache configured like:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': '<project_name>.lib.caches.memcache_cache.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
    }
}
```

After migrating to 1.6 we're getting error:

```
django.core.cache.backends.base.InvalidCacheBackendError: Could not find backend '<project>.lib.caches.memcache_cache.MemcachedCache': Error importing module <project>.lib.caches.memcache_cache: "No module named <project>.lib.caches.memcache_cache"
```

Any fast solution? How root of project defined in 1.6?

Comment: Your `<project_name>` package have to be on sys.path. Try `python manage.py shell` and see what is yours sys.path.

Comment: Yes, solution was `sys.path.append('<path_to_project>/../')` in `manage.py`.